# How to create a custom command in terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal, command

I need help creating a custom command in the linux terminal, for this I have the following problems, I want to do:

```
copy file path: /test /file
```

How can I insert a user `"input"` in bash format so that later the terminal understands the file I want to copy and the path?
Sorry if I don't explain myself very well ... I'm new ...

Comment: What do you mean by command? An executable? A bash function or alias? And can you clarify what you mean by "in bash format"? Overall, are you trying to mimic `cp`?

Comment: Yes, create a new alias

Answer (score 3):

First of all, do not worry about being new. We are all here to learn and help each other!

#### Assumption

From what I understand, you would like to create a Bash script which accepts user input specifying both the filename and the destination path for the file to be copied to. The code below does exactly that but note that it does not have the auto-complete feature when accepting user input.

#### Solution

`script.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# ask user for file name to be copied
read -p "Name of the file to be copied:" filevar

# ask user where they want the file to be copied to
read -p "Destination path:" pathvar 

# does the copying 
cp -- "$filevar" "$pathvar"
```

#### Usage clarification

In case you are not sure how to run the script, I will give you an example scenario. Open your terminal and make sure you are in your `Desktop` directory. To run the script, enter `./script.sh`. Then enter the file name to be copied, press `Enter`, and then enter the destination path. In your case, it is `test` (assuming you have a `test` folder on your `Desktop`). Press `Enter` one last time and the file will be copied to the destination.

Just let me know if you were expecting something different as I could not comment on your post to get more clarification due to my low reputation.

Comment: It's better to name it just `script` instead of `script.sh`. Give exec permission: `chmod +x script`